# Finding duplicates in a CSV file with whitespaces

Tags: linux, csv, uniq

I want to find duplicates in a CSV file that contains whitespaces and newlines. `sort -u` and `uniq` (on a sorted file) bomb out due to spaces and/or in the data.

The data looks something like:

```
1,"foo","foo bar",false
2,"baz","bat",true
5,,"something with a space
and a newline.",false
```

That is, comma-separated, with newlines demarcating rows.

The data can have spaces in any of its columns, so using `sort -u` or `uniq` and specifying the key is not an option.

Final sort order is not important.

Comment: and what you have done so far?

Comment: `sort -u` and `uniq` as specified above. The data needs sorting so `uniq` alone does not work, and `sort` is failing due to whitespaces and newlines. Specifically I have tried `sort` specifying ',' as the delimiter and sorting by the first key (`sort -t',' -k1 myfile.csv`), but that fails when there are newlines and I get garbled data as the output.